# Javascript I get a value from Firebase and push it into a array but it isn't really pushed

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a beginner in Javascript. My problem is:

- I declared an array

```
    var x = new Array(0, 3, 2);
```

- After that, when I pushed an element into the array, the element was pushed successfully!

```
    x.push(1);
```

```
    (4) [0, 3, 2, 1]
    0: 0
    1: 3
    2: 2
    3: 1
    length: 4
```

- But when I get a value from Firebase Cloud and push it into the array. This element isn't really pushed. I mean when I extend console and check, the new array have 17 elements, but there is a difference in the first line on the console in each example. At 2nd case, the array still display it have 3 elements.

```
    var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('PPGValues');
        starCountRef.on('value', gotData);
        function gotData(data){
          var data = data.val();
          var keys = Object.keys(data);
          for(var i=0; i < keys.length; i++){
            var k = keys[i];
            var yValue = data[k].yValue;
            x.push(Number(yValue));
          }
        }
```

```
    (3) [0, 3, 2]
    0: 0
    1: 3
    2: 2
    3: 0
    4: 2
    5: 4
    6: 3
    7: 1
    8: 0
    9: 6
    10: 6
    11: 1
    12: 9
    13: 7
    14: 5
    15: 1
    16: 0
    length: 17
```

Are there anyone who have a suggestion. Thank you so much!

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1):

If the database is as expected the code looks fine. One reason I could imagine is that you maybe console log the data outside of the callback `gotData` and don't see the expected result.

What do you see if you write the console log like this:

```js
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref("PPGValues");
starCountRef.on("value", gotData);
function gotData(data) {
  var data = data.val();
  var keys = Object.keys(data);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys[i];
    var yValue = data[k].yValue;
    x.push(Number(yValue));
  }

  console.log("x", x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. Actually, I also add a console function after gotData, and the result shows such as the final picture.

Comment: If you add it after `gotDate` you would get a wrong log. `gotData` is executet asynchronously and that measn your console log will be fired before `gotData` even gets called. That is the reason I ask where the console log is. It makes a huge differnce here where you put it in the code.